# TypeError: next is not a function when io.use(passport.authenticate('google'))

Tags: node.js, socket.io, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to use authentication with socket.io's io.use() as they've mentioned in their [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#Socket-io-uses-middleware-now). They seem to have an example of `io.use()` in which the function calls `next()`, but I am getting the error:

> TypeError: next is not a function

for using using `io.use(passport.authenticate('google'))`

**Update**

I know that the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#Socket-io-uses-middleware-now) shows that I need to pass `next` as an argument. But I cannot pass next, because the `passport.authenticate()` method is defined by passport.js, I am not declaring it there (like in the docs).

The only option I think I can use is defining a function and using `passport.authenticate` inside it. But I am not sure if that would be the correct way to go. I may also need to handle custom callback if I do so.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass next as an argument

Comment: The function `passport.authenticate` is by passpport.js, so I don't think I can pass next to it because of it's own method signature.
Should I use `passport.authenticate('google', {...}, next)`? If so, then what do I pass in next?